# The active or pending auth credentials were superseded by another call to auth

Tags: android, firebase, nest-api

I am developping an android app based on firebase that connects to the Nest API. While it worked for some time, it now rejects authentification.

I get the folowing error "The active or pending auth credentials were superseded by another call to auth" when I'm pretty sure firebaseRef.auth() method is only called once...

EDIT : I'm getting close to the 1000 Users limitation after wich we should request more users from Nest.

Any idea where this is comming from ? Can it be comming from the online service I am calling or is this necessarilly due to my code ?

thanks.

P.

Comment: firebase client version is 1.0.15

Comment: migrating to firebase-client-android-2.2.1 gives the same.

Answer (score 0):

We discovered that every time the user is passed through the Works with Nest web sign up dialog, it generates a new auth token. 
 Is it possible you've run through the process on multiple devices and generated a new auth token, invalidating your previous one?

Comment: I only authenticate with the same user same key from one device. Code is 1/ login through authentication flow 2/ catch token 3/ authenticate with token -> Failed. This used to work fine. that is why I'm questionning the 1000 users limit.